# How to group rows by specific range and conditionally?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a genetic dataset where I want to group genetic variants/rows that are physically close together in the genome. I want to group genes that are within a 500 +/- distance from certain spots in the genome per chromosome.

My 'spots' dataset is of positions that variants need to be within 500 +/- range of and looks like:

```
     chrom           min          max      low       high
       1             1000         1200     500       1700
       1             20000        20100    19500     20600
       5             900          1000     400       1500
```

My `low` and `high` columns are the ranges that I want to see if any rows in my next dataset fall into, with also accounting that the chromosome must also match.

My other dataset has a `position` value that I'm looking to see if fits in any of the ranges above with matching `chrom`:

```
Gene   chrom position 
Gene1   1    1200          
Gene2   1    10000        
Gene3   5    500     
Gene4   1    560
Gene5   1    20100
```

I've tried using `group_by()` and `between()` to set up the range, but I'm struggling to account for the *need to match the chromosome (`chrom`) between the datasets before* then searching for range.

Output would look like:

```
Gene   chrom position   Group 
Gene1   1    1200          1  #position is in one of the ranges so is in a group    
Gene2   1    10000        NA
Gene3   5    500           2  #position is in one of the ranges so is in a group
Gene4   5    560           2  #position is in the same range as above so joins that group
Gene5   1    20100         3  #position matches a chrom and range and so gets a group corresponding to that particular chrom and range
```

Gene3 and Gene4 are not in group 1 because they are on a different `chrom`.

So I am creating a `Group` column with a shared number for all rows in the same range on the same chromosome, or NA if their `position` doesn't match in any range in the first dataset. Ideally I am looking for a dplyr solution as that is what I normally use, but my real data is also very large so any guidance that helps that would be appreciated.

Input data:

```
#df1
structure(list(chrom = c(1L, 1L, 5L), 
    min = c(1000L, 20000L, 900L), max = c(1200L, 20100L, 1000L
    ), low = c(500L, 19500L, 400L), high = c(1700L, 20600L, 1500L
    )), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

#df2

structure(list(Gene = c("Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene4", "Gene5"
), chrom = c(1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L), position = c(1200L, 10000L, 
500L, 560L, 20100L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: It just doesn't make sense right now. 500 and 560 in Gene 3 and 4 are between 500-1700 as well as 400-1500. They should be unique or you need to clarify another condition for how to pick the "group" if multiple ranges were met. As of now, your question is unclear.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to clarify throughout it's due to Gene 3 and 4 are on another ```chrom``` so if the ```chrom``` number is different they should be considered in a range unique to match the ```chrom``` number first. This is also the main part I'm stuck on in my question, I don't how to conditionally separate range consideration by ```chrom```

Answer (score 1):

you could possibly run the calculation in parallel on multiple cores if that is an option... I am no expert on the topic though, anyhow the example below should work for a try (the main idea is to search for one matching range per iteration/run and bind positive matches to a list)

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyr)
library(parallel)

# start parallel backend with 4 cores (or how many threads you have)
cl <- parallel::makeCluster(mc <- getOption("cl.cores", 4))
# export the data to the 
parallel::clusterExport(cl=cl, varlist=c("df1", "df2"))
# export packages
parallel::clusterEvalQ(cl, {library(dplyr)})
# set the lenght to one variable (could pass in the below function also)
l <- length(df1)
# run function on cluster
res <-parallel::parLapply(cl, 1:l, function(i){
  # select 1 range to match
  dfi <- df1[i, ]
  # full join all df2 with the only one range
  dfr <- dplyr::full_join(df2, dfi) %>% 
    # Check if values are in the range and give corresponding gene and chromosome
    dplyr::mutate(GENE_COR = ifelse(position >= low & position <= high, Gene, NA),
                  CHROM_COR = ifelse(position >= low & position <= high, chrom, NA)) %>% 
    # filter ever non match
    dplyr::filter(!is.na(GENE_COR))
  # return the info to puild list in parallel
  return(dfr)
}) 
# reduce result list build in parallel of only positive matches to a tibble
plyr::ldply(res, tibble)

  chrom  min  max low high  Gene position group GENE_COR CHROM_COR
1     1 1000 1200 500 1700 Gene1     1200     1    Gene1         1
2     5  900 1000 400 1500 Gene3      500     2    Gene3         5
3     5  900 1000 400 1500 Gene4      560     2    Gene4         5
```

Though parallelization is not always better - the dplyr solution is inside the function - just use the whole df2 instead of dfi

==================================================================

New answer:

```
# Build a group identifier
df1 <- df1 %>% dplyr::group_by(chrom) %>% dplyr::mutate(GROUP = dplyr::row_number(), GROUP2 = paste0(chrom, "_", dplyr::row_number())) %>% dplyr::ungroup()


df2 %>% 
  dplyr::full_join(df1) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(CHROM_COR = ifelse(position >= low & position <= high, chrom, NA )) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(CHROM_COR))

    Gene chrom position   min   max   low  high GROUP GROUP2 CHROM_COR
1 Gene1     1     1200  1000  1200   500  1700     1    1_1         1
2 Gene3     5      500   900  1000   400  1500     1    5_1         5
3 Gene4     1      560  1000  1200   500  1700     1    1_1         1
4 Gene5     1    20100 20000 20100 19500 20600     2    1_2         1
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this looks like it will work even with just the dplyr section it seems to run fine. Although I do not get a ```group``` column output, how do you create the ```group``` column here?

Comment: Hi, you gave group as input in df2. If you take it out, you could use the chrom column from df1 to as grouping criteria from what I understand of your data:    df1 %>% 
  dplyr::full_join(df2) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(IS = ifelse(position >= low & position <= high, 1, 0),
                CHROM = ifelse(IS == 1, chrom, NA))

Comment: I will alter my code in the answer as I somehow interchanged the df1 and df2. You want to loop through all ranges and match all each time the whole genom not vice-versa

Comment: Ah ok thank you, I'll try what you've given. I accidentally gave the output example as the input data. I've updated df2 now, I need to be able to make the ```group``` column from scratch by matching rows with the same ```chrom``` and in the same low and high range as df1

Comment: I can see the grouping is successful from looking at the output, but I need the groups to have a shared group number identifier - is there a way to add this in? Sorry for my confusion on this, have a biology background, but this looks like it's doing almost everything I am looking for

Comment: From what I understood you can use the "chom" column as group identifier or not? Just filter all non-matches and then the "chrom" automatically becomes the grouping criteria... Might be wrong here (this logic would be correct for your sample data though)

Comment: You can't as there should be multiple subgroups within one chrom grouping, although I see how I've got it in the example, sorry for this

Comment: please alter the input and output data in a way, that all possible cases are included so it becomes clear what you are looking for and what not. I am having dificulties to understand it without seeing the numbers, because as I said: as your data stands now the logic would be OK so without seeing explicite cases where and when it does not I can only be making guesses. thx

Comment: I've had a go at adding in a new example that is on ```chrom``` 1 but has a different range and so should be a different group

Comment: new example data is not wokring - you might have missed a line?

Comment: sorry about that, updated again now should work

Comment: I guess I understood it now! you need a group identifier in df1 - you can use it in the join if you create beforehande. Try this: df1 <-  df1 %>% 
                   dplyr::group_by(chrom) %>% 
                   dplyr::mutate(GROUP = dplyr::row_number()) %>% 
                   dplyr::ungroup()

Comment: will include a new part in my original answer... 1min

Comment: original answer was editted - I will be offline for a while now .. anyhow shoot a question if it does still not do what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you for this! Only problem left is that ```Gene3``` in the example is on ```chrom``` 5 but is getting put into group 1 with the genes on ```chrom``` 1 becuase the range number is similar. However it needs to be in its own group due to the different chrom. The chroms (chromosomes) are 22 groups in total, and each have values measured starting from 1-100000+ so they can have same range numbers but are different due to the chrom number. Sorry I should've defined this in my question. I will try making 22 datasets per ```chrom``` then run your grouping code in the meantime, thx again!

Comment: Hi, you need the chom and group to make a unique identifier (the GROUP is per chrom) - just editted my second try at the answer my making a unique identifier of both (GROUP and chrom). Have a look at it.